# angular code is not working inside the directive while adding it dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am adding Angular directive content dynamically, but I'm not able to add functionality like `$scope` and `Controller` inside it. How do I solve this issue? For example:

#### a.html

```
<div ng-controller="actrl">{{aname}}</div>
```

#### b.html

```
<div ng-controller="bctrl">{{bname}}</div>
```

Suppose that I have a directive with the template URL: `/a.html` and
I change it to `/b.html` dynamically, then for `b.html`, the angular functionalities (`bctrl`) are not working.

#### jQuery

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: menu.templateUrl,
  success: function(response) {                   
    jQuery("view-partial").html(response);                      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include content like this using ng-view

```
 $routeProvider
      .when('#/a.html', {
        templateUrl: 'b.html',
        controller: 'bctrl',

      });
```

Here is solution for your issue
check the link 
http://jsbin.com/voyeki/2/edit

I am complied your code with

```
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$compile){
angular.element("view-partial").html($compile(response)($scope));
});
```

Hope this is solution for your issue :-)

Comment: is there any other way? because if i switch to routing we have to change lot of coding.

Comment: peter.grman.at/dynamic-controllers-in-angularjs   you need to manually create scope object. check the link hope helps for your requirement

Comment: It not possible to create fiddle . because many things depends on dynamic.  can you please look at this code ...how can i bind instead using jQuery("view-partial").html($scope.data); -------------------------$http({
      url: menu.templateUrl,
      method: "GET"     
      }).success(function(data, status) {
       $scope.data = data;
           jQuery("view-partial").html($scope.data);
      }).error(function(data, status) {
       $scope.status = status;
     });

Comment: Thanks @sarath .Now it's working, controller code  main js file. If the controller code in partial page it's not working. please help me to resolve this issue.  example-

<div  ng-controller="Controller2">
<h1>Hello {{support.name}}</h1>
</div>
<script>
bosAppModule.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.support = {
      name: 'bagya',
      address: 'bangalore'
    };   
}]);
</script>

Comment: Write controller2 script code in external js file or all controllers code in same page

Comment: is there any way to approach partial page itself we have to include controller. either it may be  external file or same file. because we have to write lot of controller. If i include all the controllers in main page. the page get delay to load. please advice.

Comment: I am not sure but try $.getScript("") load script file before including ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `$scope` on the view :

```
<div ng-controller="actrl">{{$scope.aname}}</div>
```

You need to use directly `aname`

```
<div ng-controller="actrl">{{aname}}</div>
```

Comment: HTML Code:
 <view-partial></view-partial>  
JS Code: 

jQuery.ajax({url: menu.templateUrl,
            success: function(response) {                   
            jQuery("view-partial").html(response);                      
                    }
        });

Comment: you need to take a look at angular routing, of course it will not work because angular isn't aware of the changes you made using jquery... I suggest you to use angular routing and don't use jquery for the logical aspect of your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML Code:
 <view-partial></view-partial>  
JS Code: 

jQuery.ajax({url: menu.templateUrl,
            success: function(response) {                   
            jQuery("view-partial").html(response);                      
                    }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main.js**  for example

```
   <script>  

        var bosAppModule = angular.module("bosApp", []); 

        $http({
                 url: menu.templateUrl,
                  method: "GET"              
             }).success(function(data, status) {
              $scope.data = data;
             jQuery("view-partial").html($compile($scope.data)($scope));
                              }).error(function(data, status) {
                               $scope.status = status;
            });
        bosAppModule.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.support = {
              name: 'bagya',
              address: 'bangalore'
            };   
        }]);    
    </script>
Partial page
  <div  ng-controller="Controller2">
    <h1>Hello {{support.name}}</h1>
    </div>
```

Now it's working, if the controller code  main js file. If the controller code in partial page it's not working. please look out below code and  help me to resolve this issue.

example

```
<div  ng-controller="Controller2">
<h1>Hello {{support.name}}</h1>
</div>
<script>
bosAppModule.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.support = {
      name: 'bagya',
      address: 'bangalore'
    };   
}]);
</script>
```

Actually i need evey controller in that own partial page.